# WSO2is decision entitlement for tenants

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

What alternative I have for access to `https://xxxx/api/identity/entitlement/decision/pdp` for check access to resources using the Access Token generated from a user authenticated in a tenant ?

If I use `Authorization: Bearer <token>` in headers my response is an HTTP 401, I need to use an access token, because I don't have access to admin credentials.

Comment: are you referring this https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS550/Using+REST+APIs+via+XACML+to+Manage+Entitlement ?

Comment: Yes, exactly, but using access token and not he admin credentials of tenat.

Comment: you will need admin credentials for this service. If you are not the admin, you can ask admin to create another admin role for you.

Comment: Ok, thank you ,  I was hope can use this service with only access token.

Answer (score 1):

The permission level for this resource is defined in the 
`repository/conf/identity/identity.xml` file as below.

`<Resource context="(.*)/api/identity/entitlement/(.*)" secured="true" http-method="all">
            <Permissions>/permission/admin/manage/identity/pep</Permissions>
</Resource>`

When you generate the access token, the user of that token should have a role assigned to him with this permission. So create a role and assign this permission to that role. Then assign the role to that user. Now generate a new token(Be cautious as IS might return the existing token if it is still valid) and try the flow.